# todolist rake aborted! no such file to load -- dispatcher

Tags: ruby, rake, redmine

Trying to install https://github.com/dalyons/redmine-todos-scrum-plugin plugin, but when im doing:

```
rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production
```

there is an error occured:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- dispatcher

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate_plugins => redmine:plugins:migrate => environment
```

And with trace:

```
rake db:migrate_plugins RAILS_ENV=production -trace
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ace
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:357:in `standard_rake_options'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1298:in `parse_in_order'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1254:in `parse_in_order'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1248:in `order!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1339:in `permute!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:1360:in `parse!'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:425:in `handle_options'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:74:in `init'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `init'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:64:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23
```

GEM ENV:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [amd64-freebsd7]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby18
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - amd64-freebsd-7
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/redmine/gems
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

And redmine v2.1.0.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't dig into the trace because if you look at the README on github in the requirements section:

> Redmine 0.8.5 or later (may work on earlier versions, but not tested
>   for it) - Works best on 0.9.x
>
> Rails 2.2.1 or greater (NOTE - if you are on 0.8.x, you will have to
>   manually install a newer rails version & edit your
>   config/enviroment.rb)

Many plugins working with Redmine 2.0.x don't work with Redmine 2.1.

So, i'm not surprised that a plugin designed for the 0.8, 0.9 version is not working/installing on a fresh 2.1.x version.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install 'ace' gem:

```
$ gem install ace
```

Or add 'ace' to the Gemfile.